# Best way to build a query with condition on code-behind?

Tags: c#, java

How to make this code properly? I am not satisfied with this code, I'm lost.

I give you a simple example but the query is more complexe.

Thanks in advance.

```
string aValue;
string queryA;
string queryB;
string finalQuery;

string queryA = @"SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE column1=";
queryA += aValue;

string queryB = @"SELECT column1, column2,"

if (aValue == "all"){
   queryB += @"column3";
}
queryB += @"FROM table1 WHERE column1=";
queryB += @"'" +aValue+ "'";

private void exportExcel(){

     // change the value with a dropdownlist
     if (ddlType.selectedIndex(1))
          aValue = "typeA";
     else if(ddlType.selectedIndex(2))
          aValue = "typeB";
     else
         aValue = "all";

     // select the query
     if (aValue == "typeA")
         finalQuery = queryA;
     else if (aValue == "typeB")
         finalQuery = queryB;

     ExecQUery(finalQuery);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In both Java and C# (and pretty much any other platform) you should definitely *not* include the values directly in the SQL. That's opening up the way to SQL injection attacks, and also makes dealing with formatting for dates, times and numbers tricky.

Instead, you should use *parameterized* SQL, specifying the values in the parameters. How you do that varies between Java and C#, but the principle is the same.

Another approach on both platforms is to use an ORM of some description rather than building queries by hand. For example, in .NET you might want to use a LINQ provider of some description, and in Java you might want to use something like Hibernate. Either way you get to express your queries at a higher level of abstraction than just the raw SQL.

It's hard to give much more concrete advice without knowing what platform you're really using (or database) and without a real query to look at.

Comment: yes in reality I use "parameterized SQL" and we have not ORM. I need advice for formating the code, maybe to use an other function for build the query

Comment: @user359706: So why give an example which uses a known bad practice? And you say "we have not ORM" but why *don't* you use an ORM? You asked for ways of improving the code, and using an ORM is one way of doing that.

Comment: we don't use ORM because it's a big project, it would more complexe to change all. But I need advice for re-formating the code plz.

Comment: @user359706: Only my opinion, but refusing to refactor to a known good technology designed for higher level apps is throwing good money after bad.  An ORM is especially useful in a big project.  Unless of course your big project is already complete and you can't get buy-off at this point.  But if you must keep coding against the app, keep pushing - after the refactor, it will pay off every time you make changes in the future.

Comment: @user359706: I agree with Merlyn. How long are you expecting to maintain this code for? It's very hard to give you any sort of answer you'll be happy with when you've given us code which doesn't look like your real code (it's not parameterized) and you don't want to *really* improve it significantly, just make your clunky approach very slightly less clunky...

Answer (score 0):

I usually load it from a resource file. This gives you some freedom to change the queries (this in case you don't need to generate it dynamically with if blocks). In source code I use formatting ending my line with a comment line in order to avoid my IDE to concatenate or put it all in one like like:

```
String sql = "select " + //
    "  * " + //
    "from "+ //
    "  employee " + //
    "where " + //
    "      salary > :minSal " + //
    "  and startDate > :minStartDate";
```

And in case of conditional part I just add it with a if block. But for where statements I just add one default "1=1" in order to proceed with additional limitations, so if there is no additional limitations the query will still be valid. Suppose both where statements in the SQL bellow were added conditionally:

```
String sql = "select " + //
    "  * " + //
    "from "+ //
    "  employee " + //
    "where 1 = 1 ";
```

Until here you have your base SQL, valid, that means if not condition is added it will still be valid.

Suppose you will add salary limitation just in case if it is informed:

```
if (salary != null) {
    sql += "and salary > :minSalary";
    parameters.put("minSalary", salary);
}
```

As you can see in the same condition I add a new expression to my SQL and a parameter to a map that will be used later in execute to set the parameters to the query, that avoids you to create a second if statement just to set this parameter.

Another approach that you could take is build the entire SQL and before the execution ask for the prepared statement which parameters it needs as input and provide them. In java you can do it with:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#getParameterMetaData%28%29

I know that is not the case but if ORM is used, is common to have Builders for queries and this turns this task much easier, for example in Hibernate you could have something like:

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Restrictions.like("name", "F%")
    .addOrder( Order.asc("name") )
    .addOrder( Order.desc("age") )
    .setMaxResults(50)
    .list();
```

As it is documented at:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

That means you could do this:

```
Criteria c = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .addOrder( Order.asc("name") )
    .addOrder( Order.desc("age") )
    .setMaxResults(50);
if (name != null) {
    c.add( Restrictions.like("name", name);
}
List cats = c.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

One small change you can do is set value attribute of dropdownlist to typeA,TypeB, etc.. and get rid of the initial if conditions and variables.

eg:

```
if(ddlType.selectedValue.toString()=="typeA")
   finalQuery = queryA;
if(ddlType.selectedValue.toString()=="typeB")
   finalQuery = queryB;
```